# Cards getting superimposed over one another in android

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am trying to learn about card view.I wrote a simple code to view two cards.But the problem is that the second card is not visible.I think that first card is coinciding with the second card,that's why second card is not visible.

I have used `android:layout_marginTop="40dp"` in the second card to maintain the gap between both cards.But,then also only first card is visible.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Encrypt Mode"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:gravity="center"

    />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

       >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Decrypt Mode"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:gravity="center"

            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

How to make both cards visible ?

Comment: What kind of LinearLayout orientation do you use? =) Maybe problem in this? Try to use android:orientation="vertical"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provide orientation attribute to your linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <--child1 -->
    <--child2 -->
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

oh, add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the root LinearLayout

as

```
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Encrypt Mode"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:gravity="center"

        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Decrypt Mode"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:gravity="center"

        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```